# PySpark: Change content of one df based on content of another df

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

So i have two Dataframes.
Dataframe 1 (df_origin) contains text from different source files.

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lorem ipsum Jane dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing |
| 2 | Ut enim ad minim veniam, Max nostrud exercitation |

And then I've used a machine learning tool, which returns me a list containing names, that it found inside each text. Returning a dataframe (df_results):

| id | category | offsett | length | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person | 34 | 4 | Jane |
| 2 | Person | 36 | 3 | Max |

Now i would like to anonymize each persons name in the df_origin, based on the information from df_results.
I do have the position in the string (given by offset from the start of the string) as well as the length of the name (given by length). The goal would be to have a function look up the id of the result, match it to the id in the first df and then replace the text at the given location with ****
So that df_final would look like this:

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lorem ipsum **** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing |
| 2 | Ut enim ad minim veniam, *** nostrud exercitation |

But I'm new to PySpark, so i have no idea how to effectively solve this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace`.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('text_replaced', 
               func.expr('regexp_replace(text, concat("(", content, ")"), repeat("*", length(content)))')
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+
# |text                                                   |content|text_replaced                                          |
# +-------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+
# |Lorem ipsum Jane dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing|Jane   |Lorem ipsum **** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing|
# |Ut enim ad minim veniam, Max nostrud exercitation      |Max    |Ut enim ad minim veniam, *** nostrud exercitation      |
# +-------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```